# combine multiple columns in R into a new vector column (preferably a tidyr solution)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to combine multiple columns into a vector (ideally I would like to specify which columns using some regex or `dplyr::contains()`. Anyways, I am NOT looking to concatenate columns or a solution using `paste` (I want to be able to use an `%in%` statement on the resulting vector. I want the new column to be a vector of values, which could be unnested using `unnest_wider` or some similar function. I am sure this is possible, just can't think of the right search terms for now. This seems to be close, but does not work:

```
df <- tribble(~A, ~B,
               1, 2, 
               3, 4, 
               5, 6)

df %>%
    mutate(C = I(list(A, B)))
```

The result would look something like this

```
      A     B    C
1     1     2   c(1,2)
2     3     4   c(3,4)
3     5     6   c(5,6)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, we can either use `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(C = list(c(A, B))) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      A     B C        
#  <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
#1     1     2 <dbl [2]>
#2     3     4 <dbl [2]>
#3     5     6 <dbl [2]>
```

---

Or with `map2` which by default return a `list`.  Here, we are looping over corresponding elements of 'A', 'B', and concatenating (`c`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(C = map2(A, B, c))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      A     B C        
#   <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
#1     1     2 <dbl [2]>
#2     3     4 <dbl [2]>
#3     5     6 <dbl [2]>
```

#### Update

Based on OP's comments, if we want to create a `list` column with only columns that have a suffix `_id`

```
names(df) <- paste0(names(df), "_id")
df %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(C = list(c_across(ends_with("_id")))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   A_id  B_id C        
#  <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
#1     1     2 <dbl [2]>
#2     3     4 <dbl [2]>
#3     5     6 <dbl [2]>
```

If the substring `"_id"` is at the beginning, change the `ends_with` to `starts_with` or use `matches("^_id")`

Or with `pmap`

```
df %>%
     mutate(C = pmap(select(., ends_with("_id")), ~ c(...)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   A_id  B_id C        
#  <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
#1     1     2 <dbl [2]>
#2     3     4 <dbl [2]>
#3     5     6 <dbl [2]>
```

---

Or using `Map` from `base R`

```
df$C <-  do.call(Map, c(f = c, df[grep("_id", names(df))]))
```

Comment: Thanks, this first option does, work, any idea on how to add  a grepl command to select the variables that need to be included (say only columns with the prefix "_id")? the second option only works for me if there are max two rows, but could look into other purr  function.s

Comment: @LSmeets If you have more than one variable, you can use `pmap` instead of  `map2`

Comment: @LSmeets you may check the updated solution

Comment: @LSmeets Did you meant `prefix` or `suffix`?  If it is prefix you can either do `starts_with("_id")` or `matches("^_id")`

Comment: Yes this works! thank you. to add the filter function, simply add `%>%
  rowwise %>% filter(3 %in% C)` to any of the two options.

Comment: These are very cool solutions! In my use case, I liked the `c_across` method best, but it's slow with a giant dataset like mine (almost 4 million rows). For those who are reading this who have a large dataset, go with the `purrr::pmap` solution instead; it's much faster because it avoids having to use `rowwise`.

Comment: Now dplyr gains `pick()`, so `pmap(select(., ends_with("_id")), ~ c(...))` can be written as  `pmap(pick(ends_with("_id")), c)`.